# Hacer funcionar modal desde Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap

estoy intentando que por medio de Jquery aparezca mi modal, pero no funciona, la idea es que presionando boton "btnmodal" aparezca el modal por medio de Jquery.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CRUD Mascotas</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnmodal').click(function(){
                $('#modal').modal('show');
            });
            
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
   <div align="center" class="starter-template">
      <h1 align= "center"><b>CRUD CON AJAX</b></h1>
       <button type="button" id="btnmodal"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Nuevo
       </button> 
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Lista de mascotas</div>
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID Mascota</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Fecha De Nacimiento</th>
                <th>Raza</th>
                <th>Especie</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <?php 

                    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crud-ajax");
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM MASCOTA"); 
               while($filas=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
               { ?> 
              
              <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['idmascota']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['nombre']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['fechanacimiento']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['raza']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['especie']; ?></td>
                 <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Seleccione</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a>Eliminar</a></li>
                          <li><a>Actualizar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                 </td>
              </tr>
               <?php    
               }
               ?>   

                 
                 
           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>
   
   <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Registrar Mascota</h4>
            </div>
            <form role="form" action="" name="frmMascotas" onsubmit="Registrar(); return false">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>ID Mascota</label>
                  <input name="ID" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Nombre</label>
                  <input name="Nombre" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Fecha De Nacimiento</label>
                  <input name="Fecha" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Raza</label>
                  <input name="Raza" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Especie</label>
                  <input name="Especie" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registrar
                </button>

              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>x</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CRUD Mascotas</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->

</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> 
   <div align="center" class="starter-template">
      <h1 align= "center"><b>CRUD CON AJAX</b></h1>
       <button type="button" id="btnmodal"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>Nuevo
       </button> 
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
       <div class="panel-heading">Lista de mascotas</div>
       <table class="table">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>ID Mascota</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Fecha De Nacimiento</th>
                <th>Raza</th>
                <th>Especie</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
               <?php 

                    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","crud-ajax");
                    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM MASCOTA"); 
               while($filas=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
               { ?> 

              <tr>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['idmascota']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['nombre']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['fechanacimiento']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['raza']; ?></td>
                 <td><?php echo $filas['especie']; ?></td>
                 <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Seleccione</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                          <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li><a>Eliminar</a></li>
                          <li><a>Actualizar</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                 </td>
              </tr>
               <?php    
               }
               ?>   



           </tbody>
       </table>
   </div>

   <div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Registrar Mascota</h4>
            </div>
            <form role="form" action="" name="frmMascotas" onsubmit="Registrar(); return false">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>ID Mascota</label>
                  <input name="ID" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Nombre</label>
                  <input name="Nombre" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Fecha De Nacimiento</label>
                  <input name="Fecha" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Raza</label>
                  <input name="Raza" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Especie</label>
                  <input name="Especie" class="form-control" required>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Registrar
                </button>

              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times"></i>x</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#btnmodal').click(function(){
                $('#modal').modal('show');
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este codigo si funciona lo que hice fue eliminar como 4 librerias jquerys que tenia y pasar todo lo relacionado a javascript al final del documento. En si no se porque no funcionaba pero funciono al eliminar el penultimo jquery.

Comment: Muchas gracias, realmente lo intenté al ver ejemplos...Pero no había funcionado, es muy raro...Gracias :)

Comment: Con gusto. Es que tenia muchas versiones de jquery. Y generan conflicto.

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con:

```
$('#modal').modal();
```

Pero veo que exportas la librería de jquery 4 veces, estoy puede estar causando conflictos. El orden correcto es, primero exportar el jquery y luego la librería js de bootstrap.

También ten en cuenta que por cuestiones de ejecución lo recomendable es siempre poner las librerías y el código JavaScript el final del HTML (justo antes de cerrar el body) los css siempre en el head, esto te evitará muchos inconvenientes

Comment: Te refieres a que se debe poner solo esas 2? y en ese orden

Comment: Si esas dos y el CSS, por cuestiones de ejecución lo recomendable es siempre poner las librerías y el código JavaScript el final del HTML (justo antes de cerrar el body) los css siempre en el head, esto te evitará muchos inconvenientes